# Windows 11 kills my AlwaysOn VPN

Tags: windows-server-2019, windows-11

So here is my description of the problem with which I am struggling for a while. I am using Always ON VPN in user mode. VPN is deployed via a script, so the settings are the same for each machine. I have configured a certificate template that is used for VPN and that is also deployed the same for machines.

Now I have 3 machines in play all 3 on Win 11 Pro same version and updated in the same way. However here are the differences.

The machine which has a working VPN on Win 11 is AMD platform the other two machines are Intel-based but again the same version of Win 11.Intel machines have these processors: Machine 1: i5-1135G7; Machine 2: i7-10750H

The two machines which have a non-working VPN had perfectly fine VPN whilst still on Windows 10 as soon as I update to Win 11 it stops working. I tried this process many times to ensure the upgrade was not bad also installing from fresh Win 11 does not help and I end up with the same problem.

The affected machines give me EventID 20227, error code 812. When I try to connect the interface gives this detail which makes no sense to me:

> The connection was prevented because of a policy configured on your RAS/VPN server. Specifically, the authentication method used by the server to verify your username and password may not match the authentication method configured in your connection profile. Please contact the Administrator of the RAS server and notify them of this error.

And this message to me makes no sense as all these machines use the same certificate profile and the same VPN configuration deployed with a single script to all machines. The server-side logs are not of any help and can't find anything related to this.

So, it looks like MS made some changes on Win11 on how this is handled and for whatever reason hits my Intel-based machines only.

Any ideas?

Comment: I've seen some comments elsewhere about problems with CPU support for specific encryption algorithms in some Intel processors. Could you edit your question to include the specific Intel processor models in the two faulting Win11 machines?

Comment: @tsc_chazz Sure here are the details: Machine 1: i5-1135G7; Machine 2: i7-10750H

Comment: edit your question always instead using commenting

Comment: Long shot (as I don't use Windows). I suspect server may be forcing or preferring older and less secure (or even insecure by today's standards) authentication method for the clients in question and Windows 11 changed the defaults to something more secure and thus drops a connection. Check if the authentication settings on both ends give a chance to select common mechanism.

Comment: Checked the authentication but I am quite sure that's not the issue as other Win 11 machine has no issues with this.